# Lagrangian multiplier of a Frobenius norm constraint optimization problem

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I am facing following minimization problem:
\begin{equation}
 \begin{aligned}
  &W'=\underset{F}{\text{argmin}} \| W-F \|_F^2 \\
  s.t. ~ &F\mathbf{1}=\mathbf{1},~F=F^T
 \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
$\mathbf{1}$ is being a vector containing ones only. It's also worth mentioning, that from the constrains it follows that the matrix $F$ is doubly-stochastic. From the paper I found this problem in, I know that the Lagrangian to this problem is having following form:

$$L(F,\mu_1,\mu_2)=trace(F^TF-2W^TF)-\mu_1^T(F\mathbf{1}-\mathbf{1})-\mu_2^T(F^T\mathbf{1}-\mathbf{1})$$

I am totally lost how to form this Lagrangian equation out of the formulation given above. Can somebody help me out here?

EDIT:

Expanding the Frobenius norm and after dropping the constant I get following:
\begin{equation}
 \begin{aligned}
  \| W-F\|^2_F &= trace((W^T-F^T)(W-F)) \\
  &= trace(W^TW - W^TF - F^TW + F^TF) \\
  &= trace(F^TF - W^TF - F^TW)
 \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Is $F^TW = W^TF$ in this case? If so, I don't understand why that should be the case.

Comment: is $\mathbf 1$ the matrix with all entries 1?

Comment: Yes, that is the case.

Comment: $X$ should probably be $W$? Just expand the Frobenius norm and drop the constant term. Notice that the constraint $F^T = F$ isn't part of the Lagrangian.

Comment: @user251257 You're​ fight, it was my mistake. The constant term would be $W^TW$?

Comment: @zunder correct

Comment: @user251257 I am still not quite at the end of the reformulation. After dropping the constant I get follwoing: \begin{equation}
 \begin{aligned}
  \| W-F\|^2_F &= trace((W^T-F^T)(W-F)) \\
  &= trace(W^TW - W^TF - F^TW + F^TF) \\
  &= trace(F^TF - W^TF - F^TW)
 \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Is $F^TW = W^TF$ in this case? If so, I don't understand why that should be the case.

Comment: @user251257 ah, $W$ is being a symmetric matrix in this particular case. This and the fact that $F=F^T$ would lead to $F^TW=FW^T$, but is this also $FW^T= W^TF$ in this case?

Comment: @zunder $tr(F^TW) = tr(W^TF)$ is always true. $(F,W)\mapsto tr(F^TW)$ is in fact an inner product on space of matrices.

Comment: @user251257 got it, thank you for this explanation! The only part I am still missing is the las Lagrangian multipicator $\mu_2^T(F^T \mathbf(1) - \mathbf(1))$ which is a consequence of second constraint $F - F^T = 0$. I still do not understand how to get from $F - F^T = 0$ to $\mu_2^T(F^T \mathbf(1) - \mathbf(1))$.

Comment: @zunder you don't. As I wrote, $F^T = F$ isn't part of the Lagrangian.

Comment: @user251257 oh yes, I missed that. So the part $\mu_2^T(F^T \mathbf(1) - \mathbf(1))$ shouldn't be in the result? Where could it come from?

Comment: @user251257 aaah, I think I get it, those both Lagrangian parts stand for 1. sum of rows should be equal one ($\mu_1$) and 2. sum of columns should be equal to one as well ($\mu_2$).

Comment: @zunder well it is kind of a relaxation / compromise if you don't include $F^T = F$ in the Lagrangian.

Comment: @user251257 yes, that makes sense now. Thank you for all your help! If you want to make an answer out of it, I would accept it as the correct one.